Use switches in the .gpr file for Ada program in community compiler 25.0w
I am compiling a program with "Build & debug" and get the following error message:

[2024-12-12 11:24:45] Could not determine the project for file: D:\ada\project\Sudoku\Sudoku_main.gpr
[2024-12-12 11:24:45] Could not expand argument in command line: %fp
[2024-12-12 11:24:45] Build command not launched.

I am using following .gpr file:
with "gtkada";

project Sudoku_main is
   for Object_Dir use "./build";
   for Exec_Dir use "./execute";
   type Build_Kind is ("static", "relocatable");
   Library_Type : Build_Kind := external ("LIBRARY_TYPE", "static");
   case Library_Type is
      when "static" =>
         for Source_Dirs use ("./src",
                              "../../Standaarden/Standaard Packages/Pipe/",
                              "../../Standaarden/Standaard Packages/Init/",
                              "../../Standaarden/Standaard Packages/Strings/");
         -- "../../Standaarden/Standaard Packages/Debugging/");
         for Main use ("Sudoku_main.adb");
      when "relocatable" =>
   end case;
   package Ide is
      for Documentation_Dir use "./doc";
   end Ide;
   package Builder is
      case Library_Type is
         when "static" =>
            for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-s", "-m", "-j4", "-g");
         when "relocatable" => for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-s");
      end case;
   end Builder;
   package Compiler is
      case Library_Type is
         when "static" =>
            for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-gnatQ", "-g", "-gnata", "-gnatf");
         when "relocatable" =>
            for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-O2");
      end case;
   end Compiler;
   package Linker is
      -- for Windows production only ;; remove for Linux / Mac / Win debug
      case Library_Type is
         when "static" =>
            for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-mwindows", "-g");
         when "relocatable" =>
            for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-mwindows");
      end case;
   end Linker;
end Sudoku_main;

The program will not start; I suspect it has something to do with the switches.

What is %fp? Does it need a closing %?

I think you’ve confused gprbuild by mixing up library and executable styles.
Try:
Move the for Source_Dirs and for Main clauses to the top.
Get rid of the remaining library-delated stuff from type Build_Kind to end Case.
In package Build, choose which switches you want and just use them.
Likewise in package Compiler, package Linker.
